# Switch widget from left splitter to right splitter using wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a window with three widgets. Currently a a text box (`TextCrtl`) is taking the entire left size of the window, and on the right size, there is another text box, and under it is a button (I spitted the right side horizontally). My question is, how can I flip the widgets, to have the one long text box on the right side, and the smaller text box and button on the left side. Here is my code so far:

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Frame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):

        splitter1 = wx.SplitterWindow(self, -1,style=wx.SP_LIVE_UPDATE)
        splitter2 = wx.SplitterWindow(splitter1, -1,style=wx.SP_LIVE_UPDATE)
        self.userEnter = wx.TextCtrl(splitter2, -1)
        self.cbtn = wx.Button(splitter2, label='Close')
        self.results = wx.TextCtrl(splitter1, -1)
        #self.graphs = wx.TextCtrl(splitter1, -1)

        splitter1.SplitVertically(self.results, splitter2)
        splitter2.SplitHorizontally(self.userEnter, self.cbtn)


        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        wx.ID_EXIT = 10
        quitButton = fileMenu.Append(10, 'Quit', 'Quit this program')
        menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, quitButton) 

        self.SetSize((1090,750))
        self.SetTitle('Plancials Booky')
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def OnQuit(self, e):
        self.Close()        

def main():     
    app = wx.App()
    Frame(None)
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the order of widgets in `splitter1.SplitVertically`:

```
splitter1.SplitVertically(splitter2, self.results)
```